# Windows login against AD without joining it

Tags: windows-10, active-directory, winlogon.exe

I read [here](https://superuser.com/questions/886959/domain-authentication-without-joining-the-domain) and there that it’s possible to authenticate against an AD without the computer being a member of it.

I’m having a hard time since few days trying, I manually set the DNS on my laptop (Win10 pro) to the AD, I tried on a freshly installed VM (Win10 pro), I disabled showing the last user’s username to be able to input manually a username on login screen, I tried `DOMAIN\Administrator` and `Administrator@DOMAIN`, in both cases I get an invalid credentials message.

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Neither of those answers say you can log into a domain without actually having a user on the domain. What you want isn’t possible

Comment: It’s the computer that isn’t joined, but I’m trying to login against an AD user. `Administrator` being the AD admin

Comment: Where are you trying to login? If its the local computer, then you can only login with local accounts. A computer that is not domain joined can connect to a domain share with domain credentials though, but you cannot login locally until that computer is domain joined.

Comment: @LPChip My idea is to login “locally” (on the computer) against a domain user, for instance to apply user’s policies (auto mount shares, VPNs, …) only when logged in against a domain’s user. Are you saying that’s not possible?  I’m new to AD

Comment: To do that, you must domain join the pc. Once domain joined, you can both login locally and using a domain user. Logging in locally will not load domain policies though. Only for the domain users will those be applied. Do note that you can use a domain user without being in the network too. Working with a local account next to an AD account is not recommended.

Comment: @Max13 - What you describe isn’t possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you're trying to login to a computer using domain credentials, where the computer itself is not domain joined.

This does not work. Active Directory actively prevents this because its a security breach.

If a computer is not a member of that domain, you are not allowed to login a computer with domain credentials. You will need to use local credentials to login to that computer.

When you are logged in locally though, accessing domain services, such as network shares can be done using AD credentials. Accessing the resources should always be possible directly on IP address base.

Do note that things like group policy to automatically map network drives and such won't work because they require the computer to be domain joined.